# twisted problem, too many open files

Tags: twisted, twisted.internet

I'm using twisted with perspective broker for my distributed application. I have faced to a problem that when I try to log in more than 54 clients to my server and invoke a simple remote_call on my remote referenceable object, it receive the error : "too many open files"
But when I disconnect one client, another one can come in and get connected to the server.

Comment: Code? Stack trace? What kind of exception are you getting? We're not mind readers you know.